# org.apache.pulsar.broker.web.RestException: Policies not found for myTenant/myNamespace namespace

Tags: apache-pulsar

I am using Apache Pulsar, and I'm trying to deploy a Pulsar function, but I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.pulsar.broker.web.RestException: Policies not found for myTenant/myNamespace namespace
```

I've checked the code in my function, and everything looks fine.
I'm using Pulsar 2.6.0, but I've tried other versions and gotten the same result.

What's causing this issue? How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the tenant and namespace exist that you're trying to deploy the function/sink/source into.
If the tenant or namespace don't exist, then you will get this error because the policy doesn't yet exist. (The policy is created when the namespace is created.)

Try creating the tenant and namespace with the Admin CLI, like this:

```
bin/pulsar-admin tenants create myTenant
bin/pulsar-admin namespaces create myTenant/myNamespace
```

If you need to provide additional options, such as the roles or clusters that will be used, those need to be specified. (If you're just using Pulsar standalone, probably you won't need to worry about that.) If someone else manages the cluster (or if you don't have admin permission), you need to ensure that you're writing to the correct tenant/namespace. If you're still having issues, you will need to talk to your cluster admin.

You can find the docs here about how to use the Pulsar Admin CLI commands: http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/pulsar-admin/

More specifically, here for `tenants create`: http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/pulsar-admin/#create-4
and here for `namespaces create`: http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/pulsar-admin/#create-2